# Way to tell if a post came from an ajax call in codeigniter?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, post

I just started using CodeIgniter after using Zend for a while.  My new site has a feature where you register through Ajax.  In Zend I could use this to check if the incoming POST was through AJAX, and therefore from my site:

```
if(!$this->getRequest()->isXMLHttpRequest())
```

Is there a piece of code in CodeIgniter that does the same thing?  If I don't make sure it's an AJAX call, someone could theoretically register anything they wanted by creating a form to post to my controller.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're concerned about somebody POSTing something from another website, it makes no difference whether your handler is AJAX or not. Use CAPTCHAs and server-side authentication (e.g., pass a hidden variable to the form that is checked one the form is submitted) to control POST requests.

Comment: Couldn't they just use firebug to see the variable and include it themselves?

Comment: If you're asking about the hidden variable, you are correct. You can use Firebug, cURL, or hundreds of other methods to pass whatever POST data you want. What you'd want to do is send the user some hidden data that is unique to that user/session/time and stored in a database. When the form is submitted, you can check the hidden field passed to you against the database.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  I had been under the impression that you can't send an Ajax call outside of your own domain.  Is that not true?

Comment: You can't, but you can always spoof headers to make it look like you did.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest')) {}
```

But since you are using codeigniter, its better to use their input class . See how to do it below.

```
 if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
     //Execute Your Code
 }
```

Comment: your solution is correct, however it isn't the way it's done in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 35):

Since CodeIgniter 2.0, there is an easier way of checking for an ajax request.

Use: `$this->input->is_ajax_request();`

Doc: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Answer (score 0):

you can check it using

```
$this->input->is_ajax_request();
```

Comment: Try to Provide your answer with more details

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html?highlight=is_ajax_request#CI_Input::is_ajax_request