# codeigniter ajax form_validation (with jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to validate some fields witj ajax through codeigniter, but can't quite figure out how to it it "right".

My ajax:

```
var timeout = null;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.new-user-box input').each(function(){

        var key = $(this).attr('name');

        $(this).on("keyup", function() {
            var value = $(this).val();

            if(value=="") {
                return false;
            }

            var json = {};
            json[key] = value;
            json['ajax'] = '1';

            if (timeout) {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            }
            timeout = setTimeout( function() {
                $.ajax({
                url: 'auth/ajax_validate',
                type: 'post',
                data: json,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
                })
            }, 1000)
        });

    })

})
```

This basically lets all my input fields send their value on keyup (after 1 second).

My php (just a snippet from the username test):

```
<?php

    function ajax_validate()
    {

        // Test if the method is called by ajax and validate the input field
        if($this->input->post('ajax'))
        {
            if($this->input->post('username'))
            {
                if($this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Brugernavn', 'required|trim|min_length[1]|max_length[20]|is_unique[users.username]|xss_clean') && !$this->form_validation->run())
                {
                    $validates = 0;
                }
                else {
                    $validates = 1;
                    $error = "";
                }
                $response = array($validates,$form_error('username'));
                echo json_encode($response);
                exit;
            }
        }

    }

?>
```

The response i receive is a php error:

Message:  Undefined variable: form_error

Fatal error:  Function name must be a string in \PATH TO CODEIGNITER\application\modules\auth\controllers\auth.php on line 401

Hope someone has a clue how to fix this, or do it another way. Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take out the $ before "form_error".

```
$response = array($validates,$form_error('username'));
```

to

```
$response = array($validates,form_error('username'));
```

Comment: @SpYk3HH Yup I like it `:D`

Comment: Wow, can't believe how unbelievably stupid i feel now, that i didn't see that. Thankyou!

Comment: @Jens Ahlsten Herlevsen: are you showing the errors individualy, on each field? how do you output them in jquery?? ( i guess you dont use console.log(data) )

Answer (score 0):

Just found this:

```
$this->input->is_ajax_request();
```

from here:

[Way to tell if a post came from an ajax call in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779433/way-to-tell-if-a-post-came-from-an-ajax-call-in-codeigniter)